# msdeploy + setParameters.xml, how to set web physical file location

Tags: file, path, location, msdeploy

This question has been danced around a bit, forgive me if it is a duplicate but I haven't been able to find an exact answer.

I am trying to create a Parameters.xml for deployment configuration that specifies the destination physical file folder for a web site.  This is for an automated build using TeamCity, e.g. commandline using .deploy.cmd.

Can someone explain what I need to do?

Parameters.xml:

```
<parameter name="physicalPathLocation" description="Physical path where files for this Web service will be deployed." defaultValue="\" tags="PhysicalPath">
    <parameterEntry kind="DestinationVirtualDirectory" scope="Default\ Web\ Site/iag\.application\.services\.exampleservice/" match="" />
</parameter>
```

And in SetParameters.xml

```
<setParameter name="physicalPathLocation" value="C:\MyFolder\MySite" />
```

I suspect my problem is in how I am declaring the scope but am unsure what needs to be done.

Comment: I believe it may be "physicalPath" rather than "physicalPathLocation", but this is not well documented.

Comment: @WhatWouldBeCool - "physicalPathLocation" is Stu's arbitrarily named parameter. The parameter kind is indeed [DestinationVirtualDirectory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084%28v=WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_ParameterKindSettings)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Default Web Site/iag.application.services.exampleservice` is a virtual directory in IIS (`DestinationVirtualDirectory` is only valid for "applications"), you can probably just get away with removing the `/` suffix and not encoding it. (I've also removed the `match` attribute)

```
<parameter name="physicalPathLocation" 
           description="Physical path where files for this Web service will be deployed." 
           defaultValue="\" 
           tags="PhysicalPath"
           >
    <parameterEntry kind="DestinationVirtualDirectory" 
                    scope="Default Web Site/iag.application.services.exampleservice" />
</parameter>
```

Keep in mind that you don't *have to* declare parameters before you set them. You could just as easily declare the full parameter and set it at the same time:

```
<setParameter name="physicalPathLocation" 
              kind="DestinationVirtualDirectory" 
              scope="Default Web Site/iag.application.services.exampleservice" 
              value="C:\MyFolder\MySite" />
```

Comment: scope="/" worked for moving the site root exported with appHostConfig.