# Web Deploy setParameter.xml updating appsettings

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

I remember reading somewhere ways to update the web.config using SetParameter.xml without having it declared first in Parameter.xml? (And I was pretty sure I got it working, but now I can't find it).

Much thanks.

Comment: Saw this mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12576556/655598)